# Logan Paul camera?

Tags: canon, zoom, equipment-damage, canon-7d, superzoom

Ok in today's vlog thats 23 August from India , He had posted a vlog about capturing Eclipse .  Where he purchased a 14k dollars worth lens.

But the lens didn't work with his camera ???
 Why did that happen I believe he was using a cannon 7d or something.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHUbn8H4XTw

Instagram - @loganpaul
YouTube - Logan Paul Vlogs 
Be a Maverick 
Logan Paul.com/shop[image]

Comment: You couldn't put a link to the video about which you are asking? I guess it's this one, but I didn't watch it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHUbn8H4XTw

Comment: Yes that's the video

Comment: @LoganPaul Hilarious. If you think education is expensive, try ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All camera lenses form an image at some specific distance downstream from the lens. When imaging far distinct objects like stars or sun or moon, the image to lens distance is equal to the focal length of the lens. The focal length measurement is not taken from the middle of the lens barrel nor from the last glass lens in the barrel. Instead, it is made from a point called the “rear nodal”.  It is not likely that a person inexperienced could find this point and then mount a lens on a camera and expect an in-focus image.  In other words, lens, mount and camera body require a specific mounting arrangement.

It is possible that the lens and camera posed were correctly positioned. However,  in this instance, such a mounting likely detaches the electrical signals between camera body and lens. Should this be the case, it will be necessary to manually set the lens aperture and focus.

The real lesson is, never approach a one in a life time event and attempt to record same without pre-testing and pre-familiarization, of the equipment and accessories.